# Why am I not listed as a contributor to a project that merged my PR?

Tags: git, github, open-source, pull-request

I had a PR merged to the master branch of an open source project on GitHub. The project is not a fork, and if I view the file in the master tree that I edited in my PR, I am listed *there* as a contributor to that file.

For some reason, however, I am not appearing in the project's main "contributors" page. Does anyone know why this would be? I've already viewed [this GitHub help page about contributions showing up on my own profile](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/) but my question is about showing up in the "contributors" page of the actual project.

For reference, here is the PR in question: https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/pull/780

Comment: I suspect a delay.

Comment: It's been months since the PR was merged

Comment: I would appreciate a link to the PR.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi I just added a link to the PR to the end of OP

Comment: Seems you have earned the [contributor] badge, so I guess it's just a search mistake.

Comment: https://github.com/FancyGrid/awesome-grid/pull/19 I have a similar question, if my PR is merged, how come I'm not a contributor? [just trying to understand what I did wrong, that was my first PR]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For some cases, it could be a squash merged PR.

The authorship then completely belongs to the person who merged the PR. GitHub seems to credit you as contribution on your profile, but since it's not counted in commit there's a possibility that the changes doesn't makes you a contributor.

> When a pull request is merged and commits are squashed, only the user that merged the pull request and the user that opened the pull request receive contribution credit. No other contributors to the pull request will receive contribution credit. [link](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/)

**Update**: only the "top" 100 contributors are crawled, and it's a strict limit of 100 and cuts the rest. You only contributed one, so you're end up hiding in the cutted part.

The best way to confirm whether you have the contributor status is to use the recently implemented badge feature in the comments. You seem to have it.

Comment: Thanks. I just realized the major oversight on my part which you've pointed out here: the contributors page only lists the first 100 contributors even though when you click on its link from the project homepage it lists the full number (in this case 176 contributors). I just assumed that since I was clicking on a link that said "176 contributors" that the page it took me to showed 176 contributors, so I only ever did a full page search & looked for pagination but didn't look at the number of the last contributor on the page.